# Error on running Jmeter script through CLI

Tags: jmeter

JMeter Folder: C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
Script Folder: C:\Users\supra\OneDrive\Documents
JMeter Script Name: Google Home.jmx

While I am trying to execute Jmeter script named Google Home through cmd I am facing below error:

C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\Users\supra\OneDrive\Documents"Google Home.jmx"
An error occurred: Unknown arg: Home.jmx
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

If I change script name "Google Home.jmx" to "Google.jmx", it is running successfully.
Kindly help.

Comment: If there is space in filename put `"` around full path as "C:.....jmx"

Answer (score 0):

Either [surround the path with quotation marks](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001477.htm) like:

```
jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\supra\OneDrive\Documents\Google Home.jmx"
```

or use [URL-like encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP):

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Users\supra\OneDrive\Documents\Google%20Home.jmx
```

Also consider:

- Upgrading to the latest version of JMeter (5.4.1 as of now), you're supposed to be using the latest version of JMeter according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article
- I believe you will also need [test results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) for later analysis in listeners or via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) so consider adding `-l` command like argument:

  jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\supra\OneDrive\Documents\Google Home.jmx" -l c:\somefolder\results.jtl